# Uninitialized Constant ContactController when changing Boolean Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to archive a message (the message model is called `contacts`) from my `users#show` page and am having some difficulties.

The link is inside the `@contacts.each` loop and is like this:

```
<%= link_to archive_contact_path(contact), method: :post do %>
    <i class="icon ion-folder"></i>
<% end %>
```

Inside my `users_controller` (because this is happening on my `users#show` page), the following methods live in the private section:

```
def archive_contact
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    if @contact.update_attributes(archived: true)
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:notice] = "That message has been archived!"
    else
        redirect_to root_path
        flash[:warning] = "Oops! Something went wrong!"
    end
end

def unarchive_contact
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    if @contact.update_attributes(archived: false)
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:notice] = "That message has been unarchived!"
    else
        redirect_to root_path
        flash[:warning] = "Oops! Something went wrong!"
    end
end
```

Finally, I have the following routes:

```
post "contact/:id/archive" => "contact#archive", as: "archive_contact"
post "contact/:id/unarchive" => "contact#unarchive", as: "unarchive_contact"
```

Can anyone see why I'm getting an `uninitialized constant ContactController` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
post "contact/:id/archive" => "contact#archive", as: "archive_contact"
```

That route tells Rails: "when a request is made to 'contact/XX/archive', get an instance of ContactController, and call the action 'archive'", the "as" option tells rails to create helper named routes "archive_contact_path" and "archive_contact_url".

So, if you have a UsersController and the methods is "archive_contact", the route should be

```
post "contact/:id/archive" => "users#archive_contact", as: "archive_contact"
```

Personally, I would create a ContactsController and move both methods (un/archive) to that new controller. The links are displayed in a user's show view, but the real actions affects Contact instances.

Comment: I agree about moving it to the ContactsController.  However, when I made the changes you suggested, the new error now reads `The action 'archive_contact' could not be found for ContactsController`.

Comment: Ahhh, I figured it out.  It can't be a private method.  I removed that and it worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem lies in your routes. You're routing to `'contact#archive'` when you should be routing to `'users#archive'` because that's where the action `archive` or  `archive_contact` is, not in the nonexistent contact controller `'contact#archive'`.